# Map single object to list in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two types:

Source:

```
public class User
{
    public string City { get; set; } = "";
    public Guid Identifier { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Destination:

```
public class UserDTO 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; } = "";
}
```

How can I create a mapping with AutoMapper from the single property City to the Address list with the City property in it? This is my mapping now:

```
    public UserMappings()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Identifier));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create objects including arrays and list on the fly while mapping like below :

```
public UserMappings()
{
   CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Identifier))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Address,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(
                           src => new List<Address> { 
                                  new Address { City = src.City }
                           }));
}
```